# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'unitPrice'

Tags: python, oop

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,itemName,itemType,unitPrice):
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.itemType = itemType
        self.unitPrice = unitPrice
        

class Store:
    def __init__(self,itemInventory):
        self.itemInventory = itemInventory
    
    def buyItem(self,iname,iquantity):
        for key in self.itemInventory.keys():
            if key.lower() == iname.lower() and self.itemInventory[key] == 0:
                return None
            elif key.lower() == iname.lower() and self.itemInventory[key] < iquantity:
                bill = key.unitPrice * self.itemInventory[key]
                self.itemInventory[key] = 0
                return bill
            elif key.lower() == iname.lower() and itemInventory[key] >= iquantity:
                bill = key.unitPrice * iquantity
                self.itemInventory[key] = self.itemInventory[key] - iquantity
                return bill
            else:
                return None
    
    def prinItems(self):
        print("Stock in Hand:")
        for i,j in self.itemInventory.items():
            print(i,j)

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    n = int(input())
    itemlist = []
    itemInventory = {}
    for i in range(n):
        itemName = input()
        itemType = input()
        unitPrice = int(input())
        itemInventory[itemName] = int(input())
        itemlist.append(Item(itemName,itemType,unitPrice))
        
    obj = Store(itemInventory)
    
    orderdict = {}
    
    n1 = int(input())
    for i in range(n1):
        iname = input()
        iquantity = int(input())
        orderdict[iname] = iquantity
        
    obj.buyItem("pen",3)**strong text**
            
    obj.prinItems()
```

Why it is giving me an attribute error? Every time I run the code
it says there is a problem in lines 55 and 22.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in these two lines:

```
            bill = key.unitPrice * self.itemInventory[key]

            bill = key.unitPrice * iquantity
```

You are trying to access an attributum of the key, which is a string.
Probably you wanted to access the attributum of an instance like this:

```
self.itemInventory[key].unitPrice
```